# rsync of a single file seemingly working but actually doing nothing?

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I had a cp job of 5 GB fail on me because of file system full. After I resized the file system, I tried to resume a single file copy with rsync.

```
$ rsync --progress /source/bigfile ./bigfile
```

But it's weird, it seems to not realize that the file is already there, it seems to start over from scratch. But doesn't say where it puts any file.

If I move the bigfile out of the way and just start rsync all over, the file never shows up!

```
$ mv bigfile bigfile-away
$ rsync --progress /source/bigfile ./
```

and again rsync seems to do the copying but I never see the file appear.

This is weird!

Answer (score 2):

You are copying between two parts of the same system (or at least, that's how it looks to `rsync`). This disables most of the optimising functionality of `rsync` and it reverts to being not much more than `cp`.

If you can *guarantee* that the file has not changed you can use `--append`. For interruptible copies you may want `--partial`

You probably want to use `--times` (`-t`) to retain the file timestamps, and it sounds like you want to use `--inplace` (which is implied by the `--append` flag).

```
rsync -tvP --append /source/bigfile ./bigfile
```

When copying a file, `rsync` usually writes it to a temporary filename and then moves it instantaneously to the correct filename. The filename begins with a dot so it's classed as *hidden*; you can see it with `ls -A`. Also, without the `--partial` (part of `-P`) flag, any incomplete file is deleted from the target.